# If $N_k$ is a particular set representing the natural number $k$ and $m \le n$ and set $A= N_m \cup N_n$, then what is the cardinality of set $A$?

Tags: set-theory

1. $n$
2. $m$
3. $n-m$
4. $n+m$

I thought the answer was $D$ but it is apparently wrong. I subsituted values of 2 and 3, and 1 and 2,  for $m$ and $n$ and found that the cardinality was $n+m$. I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: Note that $N_m\subseteq N_n$...you're taking a union, not a *disjoint* union

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this will depend on how you define $N_k$. I'll try to give a general answer and a specific answer for one possible definition of $N_k$.

In general, for any two finite sets $B$ and $C$, the cardinality of $A = B \cup C$ (which we'll denote by $|A|$) is $|B| + |C| - |B \cap C|$.

So to answer your question it will depend on how exactly you define $N_k$. If you define $N_k = \{1,\dots, k\}$, then $N_m \subset N_n$ for $m < n$ (as noted by @boink). In this case, you have $N_m \cap N_n = N_m$. So,

$|N_m \cup N_n| = |N_m| + |N_n| - |N_m \cap N_n| = |N_m| + |N_n| - |N_m| = |N_n| = n$

If you are thinking of defining $N_k$ differently, you would just use the formula above to compute the cardinality of the union. So for example if you took two disjoint sets of cardinalities $n$ and $m$, then the cardinality of the union is $n+m$.

It's actually kind of fun to cook up different examples that give you different answers.